# Eclipse + MSCV + WxWidgets

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to setup a working toolchain for the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler in Eclipse with WxWidgets support.

What I did so far is:

- Compiling WxWidgets using the distributed Visual Studio .sln for VS2010 (I think Eclipse uses the same compiler etc.)
- Confirm Eclipse toolchain is working (Standard Hello World project)
- Create WxWidgets test application ([Zetcode Tutorial)](http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/firstprograms/)
- Configure Eclipse toolchain with appropriate include path, library path, preprocessor macros   (_WXDEBUG__
  WIN32
  _WINDOWS
  wxUSE_GUI=1
  _UNICODE
  UNICODE
  _DEBUG
  _WIN32_WINNT=0x0502
  _WXMSW__
  _WIN32) and code generation set to /MT or /MTd depending on debug or release build.
- I specified additional libraries ( wxmsw30ud_core.lib
  wsock32.lib
  winmm.lib
  comctl32.lib
  rpcrt4.lib
  wxexpatd.lib
  wxjpegd.lib
  wxpngd.lib
  wxregexud.lib
  wxscintillad.lib
  wxtiffd.lib
  wxzlibd.lib
  Version.lib
  opengl32.lib
  glu32.lib
  kernel32.lib
  user32.lib
  gdi32.lib
  winspool.lib
  comdlg32.lib
  advapi32.lib
  shell32.lib
  ole32.lib
  oleaut32.lib
  uuid.lib
  odbc32.lib
  odbccp32.lib ) according to [this guide](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide)

and now I end up with a Linker Error (LNK2005) on msvcrtd.lib and msvcprtd.lib.

For example:

msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z) ist bereits in libcpmtd.lib(xthrow.obj) definiert.

I am aware of the "change code generation setting to /MTd" fix, but I already use that setting and I checked the WxWidgets build configuration to specify a static library, unicode build.

So has anybody any idea why the linker comes up with that error?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Static" in wxWidgets build means just that wxWidgets is built as a static library and not a DLL. It still uses CRT DLLs by default. If you use the project files, you will need to multi-select all projects in them and change the corresponding option. Alternatively, you can build from command line using nmake, then it's enough to specify `RUNTIME_LIBS=static` as explained [here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/docs/msw/install.txt#L411).

Comment: Yay, it's working now. Thank you. I read the install.txt before but did not recognize the `RUNTIME_LIBS=static` compiler switch.